# Creating layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create a layer so that I can then proceed to add selected features to that layer. I go to simply create a new shapefile layer, and just keep getting an error saying "layer creation failed". I will attach a screenshot below.

Any ideas why it won't let me just create a new layer?

[image]

Comment: What details are included in the linked message log?

Comment: Did you select a folder where you have write permission? Otherwise QGIS uses its bin folder in C:\ , where you might have no write permission.

Comment: C:/Users/mrushton/Documents/GIS DataBase/geonb_pan_ncb.SHX.Try --config SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX true to restore or create it)
2018-05-25T11:05:29 WARNING Creation of OGR data source Test.shp failed: Failed to create file Test.shp: Permission denied

Comment: Sorry wrong message, this is what I got when I tried to add the layer to a drive I do have write permission in. : 2018-05-25T11:05:29 WARNING Creation of OGR data source Test.shp failed: Failed to create file Test.shp: Permission denied

Comment: I found that when I had this problem, the default drive for the save was not writeable.  When you enter the filename for the new layer, you need to click on the folder button to the right of the filename box and select an appropriate folder for the save.